# In Javascript While loop repeats last number when counting from 1 to 5 when run on console

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

When running following code on console:

`var counter=0; while(counter<5){ console.log(counter); counter++; }`

console o\p:
0
1
2
3
4
4

whereas for following code works fine, without repeating last value:

`for(var i=0; i<5; i++){ console.log(i); }`

console o\p:
0
1
2
3
4

Now, if I place above for loop after above mentioned while loop , output is perfectly fine:

`var counter=0; while(counter<5){ console.log(counter); counter++; }
for(var i=0; i<5; i++){ console.log(i); }`

console o\p:
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4

whereas, if I place while loop after for loop , repetition of last number found.

`for(var i=0; i<5; i++){ console.log(i); }
var counter=0;while(counter<5){ console.log(counter); counter++; }`

console o\p:
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
4

Request all to provide a reason on this unexpected behavior of while loop.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem see it working here http://jsfiddle.net/7p5L6kzz/

Comment: last `4` in first case - just value for counter++ anfter loop, so it not a `console.log` output

Comment: Looks totally fine for me - it is going through 0-4 (as you specified < 5) and then in the end it is printing the value of counter after the loop. That's where the double 4 is coming from in console.

Comment: Note that in the `for` loop version, instead of repeating the 4, you instead see `undefined` on the console - ie it's still displaying something "extra".

Comment: @andrew thanks for reviewing my edit ;) I noticed when it was too late that it was wrong

Comment: @depperm : I am using firebug console. that must be due to different way of js engine implementation.

Comment: @Grundy : Thanks for input, but why isn't happening when I am adding a for loop beneath while.

Comment: @andrew : thx buddy, trying to start with JS :P

Comment: as say @JamesThorpe: _instead of repeating the 4, you instead see `undefined` on the console_

Comment: I have forgotten the explanation why, but there is some sort of delay in ++ operators. For your first example, you can ensure this doesn't happen by doing the addition explicitly i.e. var counter=0; while(counter<5){ console.log(counter); counter = counter + 1; }

Comment: @HockeyJ That simply changes it from displaying an extra 4 to displaying an "extra" 5.

Comment: Thanks Grundy, James, Nit...
Now I do have a reason for this abrupt behavior, 

well I tried this code on 
Chromium Version 37.0.2062.120 on Ubuntu 14.04 (281580) (64-bit)
& Firebug 2.0.11 on Firefox 38.0, Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu canonical - 1.0
and still cannot find that undefined on using for loop next to while.

Thank you everyone for your support.

Comment: @FelixKling : Buddy, why did you marked this question as duplicate.
This question was asked in July 2015, and you marked it as a duplicate of a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454291/javascript-while-loop-return-value) which was asked 8 months later i.e. Feb, 2016.

Answer (score 9):

When performing operations in the console, the return value of the last executed line is always output.

That means that simply writing

```
var counter = 0; ++counter;
```

will log `1` to the console.

The same is happening in your loop, the return value of the last `counter++` is output to the console as the value of the last executed expression.

Comment: In Chrome (not sure about other browsers), this is indicated by a small grey arrow.

Comment: Thank you for your input,
"he return value of the last executed line is always output."

So why is it not happening when I am adding a for loop after while.

Comment: @Sarge It _is_ happening, see my comment above on the question.  In this case, the "return value of the last executed line" is `undefined`, which you _do_ see after the `for` loop version.

Answer (score 2):

The output of the log method depends on the javascript engine of the browser. The last value printed is not output of the loop itself.

Try: var counter=0; while(counter<5){ console.log(counter++); }