# Javascript while loop return value

Tags: javascript, loops, syntax, while-loop

I have a simple question regarding while loop in Javascript.
When I run this simple loop in browser console:

```js
var count = 0;
while (count < 10) {
    console.log(count);
    count++;
}
```

The output to console log is 0,1,2...9. *(as expected)*.
However there is one more number which is returned to the console:

```
<- 9
```

Where does this return value come from?

I assume this is the return value of `count++ expression`. But why is the value not returned by every single loop?

Is it possible to somehow catch that returned value to a variable?

Comment: I am getting only 0-9

Comment: @PrakashSharma Paste it straight into the console - the OP is talking about the [value displayed after running the code](http://imgur.com/TJxx2Vf).

Comment: Please follow this link, it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434942/in-javascript-while-loop-repeats-last-number-when-counting-from-1-to-5-when-run?noredirect=1#comment59737852_31434942

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read-eval-print-loops (REPLs) like browser consoles show the last result that the code generated. Somewhat surprisingly, JavaScript `while` loops and blocks have a result. For blocks, it's the result of the last statement in the block. For `while` statements, it's the result of the last iteration of the statement attached to the `while` (a block in your case).

Here's a simpler example with just a block:

```
{1 + 1; 3 + 3;}
```

In a REPL like the browser console, the above will show you 6, because it's a block containing two [*ExpressionStatements*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-expression-statement). The result of the first ExpressionStatement is 2 (that result is thrown away), and the result of the second one is 6, so the result of the block is 6. This is [covered in the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-block-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> 5. Let *blockValue* be the result of evaluating *StatementList*.
> 6. Set the running execution context’s LexicalEnvironment to oldEnv.
> 7. Return *blockValue*.

`while` loop results are [covered here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-while-statement-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation).

> Is it possible to somehow catch that returned value to a variable?

No, these results are not accessible in the code. E.g., you can't do `var x = while (count < 10 { count++; });` or similar. You'd have to capture the result you want *inside* the loop/block/etc., assigning it to a variable or similar. Or (and I'm **not** suggesting this), use `eval` [as Alin points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35454663/157247).

Answer (score 3):

When you run code directly in the browser console, it runs the code then logs the value of the last expression executed, in this case the value of `count++`, which at the final execution is `9` (it gets changed to `10` with the post-increment operator, ie after the value `9` is "read").

If you changed your code to:

```
var count = 0;
while (count < 10) {
  console.log(count);
  ++count;
}
```

It would instead log `<- 10`.

> But why is the value not returned by every single loop?

Because it's not being returned at all, it's just the behaviour of the console.

> Is it possible to somehow catch that returned value to a variable?

Yes, but you'll need to assign it:

```
var count = 0;
var lastcount;
while (count < 10) {
  console.log(count);
  lastcount = count++;
}

console.log(lastcount);
```

Note that if you run this snippet in the console, you'll get two `9`s logged (one from the final loop, one from the extra `console.log`) followed by `<- undefined`, because the last `console.log` returns `undefined`.

Comment: OK, got it now.
The logged value after the loop is always the last executed expression.

I was thinking if it has some connection to the while condition. But it has not. Basically whatever expression is last it goes to the console log.

Thanks!

Comment: @sachad Check out the answer by T.J. Crowder - while mine is right in what it's recording, his is more technically accurate in how it's getting there (I learnt something new today!).

Comment: @James Thorpe I don't think your answer is entirely accurate. There is actually a return value, and you can, sort of, catch it without assigning it.

Comment: @AlinPurcaru: Only with `eval`, as you pointed out, which is really meta-programming. (But it's a good point.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer can be found in the [behavior of eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Last_expression_is_evaluated):

> eval() returns the value of the last expression evaluated.

What you throw in the console is most probably put through an `eval()` (or something similar). And the last evaluated expression, in your case `count++` is returned and then logged to the console. (the value is **9**, and not **10**, because of post-incrementation).

I don't think you can store the result of the evaluation, unless you explicitly put it through another `eval()`.

```
var x = eval("var count = 0;while (count < 10) {console.log(count);count++;};");
```

Or, in the Google Chrome console, you can use [`$_`](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api).