# extra output after loop

Tags: javascript, loops, console.log

I am learning JavaScript on Codecademy. I am finding so many outputs like below when I use while loop.

```
for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
        console.log("Dhanu identify problems and solve them");
}

var loop = 0;
while(loop<5){
    console.log("Do some more");
    loop++;
}
```

I am getting an unwanted output in the last line as 4.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript while loop return value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454291/javascript-while-loop-return-value)

Comment: @Reddy Try running it in a browser console, the 4 still shows up. I guess it's the result of the last assignment which is returned and printed

Comment: This may be an issue with the Codecademy output. If there are no other lines of code, this would definitely not print a "4" (as you can see in this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/w14r4psr/). I would recommend asking the question on the Codecademy forum.

Comment: @chrki Right.. when I paste it in console it does show the 4.. But when I put this is fiddle its different..

Answer (score 2):

The output you get is simply console.log which logs the last known value of the 'loop' variable: (here in firefox):

[image]

It's absolutely not related to your code and you don't have to worry about that.

As stated in another answer, debug console use to log the result of the last line (probably because they are meant to debug).

For example the statement "i = 1" evaluates to "1":

[image]

while the statement "var i = 1;" evaluates to "undefined", hence logging "undefined"

you can observe the same behavior by invoking eval on those statements:

[image]

Comment: `The output you get is simply console.log which logs the last known value of the 'loop' variable:` But why?

Comment: because of the internal implementation of debug panel (which I don't really know in depth), which is probably based somehow on eval (see my edited answer)

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing that because the last statement in your while loop is loop++, which "returns" the current value of loop.  This is just a side effect of running code in a console like this.  Consoles are basically read-execute-print-loops (REPL), and so they need something to print.  If you ran this as a script in a webpage you would not see `4`

Comment: Thanks. I knew it is not something that I should worry about. But still needed to know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

when you write any statement in developer console then last returned value will be printed...

for example

```
var a;
```

it prints undefined on console.

```
a = 10;
```

it prints 10 on console.

```
a = 10; a = a + 5;
```

it prints 15 on console.

simply when we assign any values or increment or decrement numbers then it returns value after performing that operation...

so, in the above or below code

```
var loop = 0;
while(loop<5){
    console.log("Do some more");
    loop++;
}
```

finally loop++ is 4.