# Unclear behavior of While loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

As someone new to js, I was playing with loops when I encountered some peculiar behavior with the following code:

```js
var i = 5;

while(i!=0){
  console.log(i);
  i--;
}
```

```
OUTPUT: 543211
```

I replicated the same code in c++ :

```cpp
int i = 5;

while(i!=0){
  cout<<i;
  i--;
}
```

```
OUTPUT: 54321
```

It'd help to know if I'm missing some important differences between the two languages.

Comment: Running your code in the above snippet doesn't include the last one.

Comment: I am getting 54321 in both cases.

Comment: That said there are important differences between the way closures work in js/functional-coding & c++/procedural coding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277/what-is-the-difference-between-procedural-programming-and-functional-programming

Comment: Thanks! There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454291/javascript-while-loop-return-value). Think this query can be closed now.

Answer (score 6):

If you run the code in the browser console, whatever the last statement evaluates to will log to the console as well.  It's not actually getting `console.log`'d, though.

For example, if you do this:

```
var i = 5;

while(i!=0){
    console.log(i);
    i--; 
    '';
}
```

At the end of your list you will see `''`